# How to get all the data attributes with same class name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following `data` attributes

```
<li data-tes='rwer-234;sdf-23;gfd-345' class='sel'>Some text</li>
<li data-tes='zxc-23;vcx-12' class='sel'>Some text1</li>
```

I tried

```
$('.sel').each(function(){
     console.log( $('.sel').data('tes') );
})
```

Getting output as `undefined.`

Comment: Is your jQuery version 1.7+? The .data tag came in around then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things to look at:

The first is that within your `each` iterator function, you're doing `$('.sel').data('tes')`, which will only ever look at the *first* element matching `.tes` in the document. If you want to look at the attribute for the *current* element being iterated in the loop, use `$(this).data('tes')` instead:

```
$('.sel').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('tes'));
    // Here ----^^^^^^^
});
```

(Or if you just need to get the value and you aren't using the various other features of `data`, just use `attr`: `$(this).attr('data-tes')`.)

The second thing is to make sure these elements exist when that code runs. Two ways to do that:

1. Make sure the `script` tag containing the code is *below* the tags defining the elements in the HTML (which is [recommended](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)):

   ```
   ...content...
   <script>/* ...your code here... */</script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Or alternately if you don't control where the `script` tags go, use jQuery's `ready` callback, which will call a function you provide on "DOM ready" (when the elements are there):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       /* ...your code here... */
   });
   ```

Comment: Calm down, I didn't downvote you. My point is what he posted is the same as what you have. That wasn't the problem.

Comment: The code is different but they still yielded the exact same results. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I get your point, he seemed upset because he thought I downvoted him. It's not that big of a deal ;). I update his solution with mine and deleted mine as a sign of sportsmanship. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 $('.sel').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-tes'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of improving filtering, I would say

```
document.ready(function(){
   $('li .sel').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('data-tes'));
   });
});
```

You're probably getting an undefined because of your script being executed before the page has loaded. For avoiding such behavior you need to include your code inside a **document.ready()** to make sure it's executed when it needs to be.

Comment: `$('li .sel')` should be `$('li.sel')` or `$('.sel')`

Comment: Nope, $('.sel') would look for elements with 'sel' CSS class in the whole document. That is bad for performance and can give you unwanted results. The first suggestion is fine. I do it that way for readability.